# how can I change the color of my hand png image in xcode iphone app?

Tags: png

How can I change the color in my hand png image?  I have developed an iphone app with the image of a hand.  But I don't know how to change the skintone color of the hand.  Can you give me some help how I can change the skintone color of my hand image (png) format in my xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a half-transparent UIImage - Overlay and pass the colors on it. Or do you mean something else?